# how to put 2 css elements in the same row (one next to each other)?

Tags: html, css

I have this 2 css elements:

css file

```
.chat .messages {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: calc(100% - 6em);
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    width: calc(100% - 11em);
    margin: 1em;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 18px #fff;
    float: left;
}

.chat .users {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: calc(100% - 6em);
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    width: calc(11em);
    margin: 1em;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 18px #fff;
    float: left;
}
```

html file:

```
<div class="members">
    </div>

    <div class="users"></div>
```

I want them to be at the same line. right now each of them is in a seprated line.

Also, how I align one element to the right and one to the left?

conditon now:

```
 ___
|   |
|   |
|   |
 ____

__________________
|                |
|                |
|                |
|________________|
```

what I want:

```
 ___      ________________
|   |    |               |
|        |               |     
|   |    |               |
|   |    |               |
 ____     ________________
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are a bunch of ways to align items side-by-side. 
i made an example with `float:left;` . it works also with `display:inline-block`

but you need to set the `width` of the 2 `divs` keeping in mind that they need to fit next to eachother. so either you use percentage for example `80%` and `20%` either if you want to use `calc()` , calculate the widths so they will fit...otherwise they will stack one after the other

in your case, `.users` has width of `11em` and `margin:1em` plus a `border` of `1 px` . so first you need to set `box-sizing:border-box` so the `border:1px` is inside it's `11em` width and doesn't make the element wider

then you need to calculate that the `.users` actually occupies `11em+2em=13em` , 2em because of the `margin-left:1em` and `margin-right:1em`

the same with `members` which has `margin:1em` so you need to keep `2em` in mind when calculating the width of `members` ( also do not forget to add `box-sizing:border-box` to this element too )

so finally, `members` will have a width of `100% - .usersWidth - 2em(from margin)` so

```
.members {
     width:calc(100%-15em)
}
```

```css
.members {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: calc(100% - 6em);
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    width: calc(100% - 15em);
    margin: 1em;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 18px #fff;
    float:left;
    height:100px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    
}

.users {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: calc(100% - 6em);
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    width: 11em;
    margin: 1em;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 18px #fff;
    float:left;
     height:100px;
     box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="members">
    </div>

    <div class="users"></div>
```

**P.S.** using `display:inline-block` will add the '*well-known additional white-space*' between the elements, there are some ways to deal with that whitespace, but i suggest you use `float:left` as the example above.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.messages {
  
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: calc(100% - 6em);
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    width: calc(60% - 11em);
    margin: 1em;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 18px #fff;
    float: left;
}

.users {
  
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: calc(40% - 6em);
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    margin: 1em;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 18px #fff;
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="messages">
this is message area
    </div>

    <div class="users">
this is users area
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm addressing your specific case in this pen: http://codepen.io/memoblue/pen/OXqQvW

Basically your code works, but you're not taking the box model in consideration when calculating your elements width, so they're wider than you think and they don't fit on 1 line. By default, the width doesn't include padding or border. to fix that, you can use:

`* { box-sizing: border-box; }` which will make ALL elements widths include those.

But you still need to add the margins to the equation. so if one element is `11em` wide but has `1em` margin on each side, you need to give the other element `calc(100% - (11em + 2em + 1em))`. The `+2em` is for the margin on each side of the first one, and the `+1em` is for the margin on one side of the other element.

I have to say though: you should probably just use flexbox. It will make your life way easier. I have a bunch of [layout examples for flexbox](http://codepen.io/collection/DjOEew/) on codepen.

Hope that helps!